# How to properly set spark.driver.log.dfsDir parameter?

Tags: apache-spark

Using Spark 3.1.1

How to properly set this `spark.driver.log.dfsDir`?

My `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.eventLog.dir                   hdfs://namenode:9000/shared/spark-logs
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs://namenode:9000/shared/spark-logs
spark.history.fs.update.interval   30s
spark.history.ui.port             8099
spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled   true
spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge    30d
spark.driver.log.persistToDfs.enabled true
spark.driver.log.dfsDir            hdfs://namenode:9000/shared/driver-logs
```

I get the following error when using spark-submit on my spark driver.

```
21/05/19 15:05:34 ERROR DriverLogger: Could not persist driver logs to dfs
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /home/app/odm-spark/hdfs:/namenode:9000/shared/driver-logs from /home/app/odm-spark/hdfs:/namenode:9000/shared/driver-logs is not a valid DFS filename.
```

Why does it prefix the app location to the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to set it is:

```
spark.driver.log.dfsDir           /shared/driver-logs
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be an error in earlier "implementations" of how `spark.driver.log.dfsDir` is handled (yet cannot confirm it) since the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/configuration.html) says:

> **spark.driver.log.dfsDir** Base directory in which Spark driver logs are synced, if `spark.driver.log.persistToDfs.enabled` is `true`. Within this base directory, each application logs the driver logs to an application specific file.

There is [this section](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/security.html#persisting-driver-logs-in-client-mode) also:

> If your applications persist driver logs in client mode by enabling `spark.driver.log.persistToDfs.enabled`, the directory where the driver logs go (`spark.driver.log.dfsDir`) should be manually created with proper permissions.

The gives this "feeling" that the directory is the root directory of any driver logs to be copied to.

---

This line in the source code (the [DriverLogger](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/276aaaae8d404975f8701089e9f4dfecd16e0d9f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/logging/DriverLogger.scala#L107) that is responsible for copying driver logs) leaves no doubts to me:

```
val rootDir = conf.get(DRIVER_LOG_DFS_DIR).get
```